# How to work with multiple Put and Post methods in Asp.net web Api 2

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

In my controller below I have 2 methods using Put and Patch verbs which I want to call on different times, as you can see I am trying to pass the json objectt but but when ever I am running the project and trying to call the api i am getting this error 
"**Multiple actions were found that match the request**"

I am sure I am messing the route but don't know what exactly where I am doing wrong,  here is the controller code

```
[ApiVersion1RoutePrefix("tests")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{


       [Route("{}", Name = "PackageDropOffLocation")]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IHttpActionResult PackageDropOffLocation(HttpRequestMessage, PackageDropOffLocationRequest packageDropOffLocationRequest)
    {
        return null;

    }

    [Route("", Name = "PackageOnBoard")]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IHttpActionResult PackageBoarded(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, PackageBoardedRequest packageBoardedRequest)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
  public class PackageBoardedRequest
{
    public string PackageId { get; set; }

}

  public class PackageDropOffLocationRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Try replacing Route("", Name="PackageDropOffLocation")] with Route("PackageDropOffLocation/{}") and similarly for PackageOnBoard

Comment: Nigel, it worked, thanks, how can I mark your answer as accepted ?

Comment: I was answering the question on the train, so I was not certain that it was correct. I have put my comment into a propper answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the Route attributes:

```
[ApiVersion1RoutePrefix("tests")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{


    [Route("PackageDropOffLocation/{}")]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IHttpActionResult PackageDropOffLocation(HttpRequestMessage, PackageDropOffLocationRequest packageDropOffLocationRequest)
    {
        return null;

    }

    [Route("PackageOnBoard")]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPatch]
    public IHttpActionResult PackageBoarded(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, PackageBoardedRequest packageBoardedRequest)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
  public class PackageBoardedRequest
{
    public string PackageId { get; set; }

}

  public class PackageDropOffLocationRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

}
```